# length of c when calulating using sines

Tags: geometry

I cannot understand how i get a negative answer. I have a triangle with three angles and one side. To get another side $c$ I used the below calculation but got a negative answer.

Given that $\frac{c}{\sin C} = \frac{b}{\sin B}$ and the following calculation is made: $$c= \frac{10\times\sin 90}{\sin 68.47}$$ or $c= (10\times 0.894)/ -0.60123$ I get a negative answer for $c$?

Answer (score 3):

The 90 and 68.47 are in degrees, you need change the calculator to **degree** mode

The calculator is set to radians mode which is giving you those answers